# BLOB is not encoding the data? Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, blob, sqldatatypes

I am new to SQL databases and I am learning about the BLOB data type.
My SQL table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   NAME VARCHAR(20),
   AGE INT,
   CITY VARCHAR(20),
   FILE BLOB);
```

I insert values into it using the command line as I was observing the behavior of the BLOB field. According to my knowledge BLOB field encoded the data. But it is not showing me the encoded data when I retrieve all the records. I inserted the following values:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Neha', 21, 'Lahore', 'Computer Science');
```

It is showing me the following output:

[image]

Please help me how this is happening. What is the right concept of this.

Comment: what do you mean by "encoding" it?  blob just stores up to 65535 bytes of data, it doesn't do anything special with it.  can you explain what you expected to see?

Comment: I was following this article. Can you please observe the behavior of the blob here and help me out?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql/

Comment: that's more about the special nature of character type fields.  character types have an encoding and a collation; non-character types (blob or binary types) do not.  that means if you try to store character data, it will store the encoded value but depend on the client knowing what to do with it when you read it.  you will likely see no difference if just storing ASCII character data, though.  that is an obsolete page, though; "utf8" is deprecated and you should use "utf8mb4" instead (though I think there are plans to rename utf8 to utf8mb3 and have utf8 mean utfmb4).

Comment: again, it would be helpful to know what you expected to see.

Comment: okay so as mentioned in the article I shared, when they enter the string in a blob field it is stored as an encoded value and it is showing some encoded data in the blob field when they retrieve the rows. My question is when I did the same, why I didn't get the encoded output? I hope I explained the problem clearly.

Comment: no.  you are seeing the encoded output.  again, please explain what you expected to see.  unless your client is using UTF16 or UCS2 or the like for character encoding, if you store the characters "Computer Science", that is going to encode as just the bytes "Computer Science".  If you were storing accented characters and your client is using utf8, or you are storing emojis or something, you would see a difference between character and non-character data

Comment: Store text in a `TEXT` column, not a `BLOB` column.  Why might you ever need to covert a Blob into a Text string?  There is essentially no use for UTF16 or UCS2, unless the text you are receiving is encoded that way; I would convert it to utf8 asap.